# How can I change a string using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a string `Feb 2012`. How can I convert it to `FEBRUARY 2012`. Actually I have a whole array `['Jan 2011', 'Feb 2011', 'Mar 2011', ... ]` I need to convert each element and get `['JANUARY 2011', ...]`

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the strings are always formatted as '{monthShortForm} {year}', you can do the following:

```
var input = 'Jan 2011';
var parts = input.split(' ');
var output = longForm[parts[0].toLowerCase()] + ' ' + parts[1];
```

where longForm is a map like so

```
longForm = { 'jan': 'JANUARY', 'feb': 'FEBRUARY', /* etc */ };
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dt = new Date("Feb 2012"), // FEBRUARY 2012
    m_names = ["JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "March", 
"April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
"October", "November", "December"];

var curr_month = dt.getMonth(),
    curr_year = dt.getFullYear();

console.log(m_names[curr_month] + " " + curr_year);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myDate = new Date(Date.parse("Mar 2012"));
var monthNum = myDate.getMonth();
var year = myDate.getFullYear();
```

Now turn the monthNum into a string. I suggest an array of 12 strings, and array[monthNum] to get the proper one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be doing other time and date based manipulations in your app, I'd recommend using Moment.js (http://momentjs.com/). It's a really powerful library - perhaps a little too much so if this is all you need to do - but worth looking into anyway.

To answer your question with Moment.js, this is the snippet you'd need:

```
moment('Feb 2011', 'MMM YYYY').format('MMMM YYYY').toUpperCase();
// FEBRUARY 2011
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this using jQuery:**

```
var arr = ["Jan 2011", "Feb 2011", "Mar 2011"];
var name = ["JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH"];
var list = new Array();

// Loop through the array arr
$.each(arr, function(i, value) {

    // Convert the month names
    var month = name[i];
    var year = value.split(" ")[1];

    // Display the result
    alert(month + ' ' + year);  

    // Add elements to a new array
    list.push(month + ' ' + year);
});​

console.log(list);
```

**Console Result:**

```
["JANUARY 2011", "FEBRUARY 2011", "MARCH 2011"]
```

Hope this helps!